# CSS3 multi-column layout and Image span

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can we have an image which spans over multiple columns which is created using CSS3 multicolumn property in an Html page. Here is my column layout style

```
div#column {
        margin-left:20px;
        -moz-column-width: 250px;
        -moz-column-gap: 20px;
        -webkit-column-width: 250px;
        -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
        height: 850px;
      }
```

I need to place an image within this column layout which spans over atleast 2 or 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically there is [`column-span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-span), however it doesn't seem to be supported by any browser currently.

You could try with `position:absolute` as Simon suggests, but I doubt you will can satisfactory results and I don't think there is any other reasonable workaround.

Maybe there are JavaScript libraries that can do it...

Answer (score 0):

Add a width on your div and add this style

```
column-count:3;
-moz-column-count:3;
-webkit-column-count:3;
```

See reference: [>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484215/how-to-make-floating-div-list-appear-in-columns-not-rows)

Answer (score 0):

I asked @Krishna to post this question since our other SO question/answer session [Increase font size with JavaScript around fixed floated images in CSS columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405789/increase-font-size-with-javascript-around-fixed-floated-images-in-css-columns) was getting off-topic, i.e. it was solved and this image spanning multiple columns warranted a new question.

So, my thoughts so far...

`column-span` is working in Webkit (Chrome12) for me. Check out the [quirksmode demo page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html). However, the bad news is that it doesn't help solve this problem as the image that needs to span multiple columns still gets clipped at the `column-width`, so I don't think it is the solution.

For now I think the only solution is to do the columns yourself in JavaScript, or maybe try and use/modify the [jQuery columnizer plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/).

Oh and I just found this other question [CSS3 Columns and Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577380/css3-columns-and-images) which basically agrees that it is impossible without JavaScript.

There is already have a lot of JavaScript for your font increase/decrease (different question, see [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kn74j/18/)) so it would have been great if CSS supported this natively. All we want is big [Yoda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda) to spill over into the second column :-)

So I think that the only solution currently is:

1. For each image that is greater then the width of a column, work out how much into the next column it would be (including the `column-gap`)
2. Add a spacer floating `<div>` in the next where the image needs to overlap to, so that the words correctly continue to flow around and below the image
3. Absolutely position a copy of the image over the top.

I just hope you don't want images that span more than 2 columns otherwise it's going to complicate an already complex solution!

Answer (score -1):

Use position:absolute, like this:

```
#image {
    position:absolute;
    top:300px; //distance from top
    left:200px; //distance from left
    width:600px; //image width
    height:400px; //image height
}
```

Comment: by giving position absolute to the image, the text went downwards to the image.

Comment: @Krishna, what exactly do you mean by that? The text went under the image? In that case, put the text in a DIV and apply this style to it: margin-top:image-height-in-pixels;

Comment: @Simon..you mentioned the right problem, the text went under the image. By giving the margin-top style to the div works but it applies to all columns. Please look at the style which i given to text div. say. if had given 3 columns text and my image spans over two columns. Then by applying a margin top to that div causes third column to come down, so there will be a blank space. Is there anyway that we can remove this.