# How to make floating DIV list appear in columns, not rows

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a HTML layout puzzle on my hands. I have a large alphabetical list, generated by my PHP app, and I need to output it on a web page. The markup generated look like this:

```
<div class="list_item">A</div>
<div class="list_item">B</div>
<div class="list_item">C</div>
<div class="list_item">D</div>
<div class="list_item">E</div>
<div class="list_item">F</div>
<div class="list_item">G</div>
<div class="list_item">H</div>
...
```

The stylesheet looks like this:

```
.list_item {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;

    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Rendered result:

[image: Rendered result]

As you can see, this is not very readable, I would expect DIV's to be outputted in two columns, so the first columns would contain "A B C D" and the second one "E F G H".

Is there a way to do this, without changing the markup? It's possible, to add different class, to even and odd divs, but since divs are outputted in a loop, theres is no way split them differently.

See a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KZcCM/

Note: I already solved it by splitting the list in two parts by PHP, but I want to know, if there is a HTML/CSS solution here.

Comment: Do you want to split it alphabetically or height-wise? Personally I prefer it floated as you know "A" is at the top and "Z" is at the bottom.

Comment: When you have a class called "list_item", you know it's time to start using the `li` (list item) tag instead, along with `ul`.

Comment: I think the best way for you to do this is to split the left column and right column in two seperate divs.

Comment: @thirtydot in a real world, there is a very complicated markup inside of every DIV.

Comment: @Silver Light: Anything you can put inside a `div`, you can put inside an `li`. Just saying..

Comment: Here was my attemp: http://jsfiddle.net/KZcCM/2/

Comment: Does this have to work in Internet Explorer? It's become a rather contentious point.

Comment: @thirtydot Well, 20% of my audience uses IE. But I think, if it will work in IE9, then those 20% can see "not-so-beutiful" list until they upgrade :)

Comment: @Silver Light: The CSS3 columns won't work in even IE9. Your options, as I see them: use CSS3 columns, forget about IE users having the right order boxes, or; use CSS3 columns, but use the jQuery plugin workaround to make it work in IE, or; keep what you have, or; do what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on which browsers you need to support, you can use the new CSS3 `column-count` property.

With a simple list mark up

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Use this CSS:

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P3sX3/) - although it's not supported in any version of IE yet.  To support older browsers there are jQuery solutions, such as [Columnizer jQuery Plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/), that you can use as well as, or instead of the CSS3 solution,

Comment: Hey, nice! Good answer. Bonus points for suggesting portable alternatives to the same approach.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Marcel was faster, but I am accepting your answer, since you have mentioned alternative for IE

Answer (score 10):

Using your markup, a CSS3 solution would look like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="list_item">A</div>
    <div class="list_item">B</div>
    <div class="list_item">C</div>
    <div class="list_item">D</div>
    <div class="list_item">E</div>
    <div class="list_item">F</div>
    <div class="list_item">G</div>
    <div class="list_item">H</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.list_item {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
#wrap {
    width:460px;
    column-count:2;
    column-gap:20px;
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -moz-column-gap:20px;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-gap:20px;
}
```

With this method you get the added benefit of the column heights being equal, no matter the content of each inner `<div>`.

If it's not plainly obvious by all the vendor-specific prefixes, the browser support for this is restricted to modern browsers (the way I like it) so it's not really production-ready code (unless you like to be edgy).

#### Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/tk2tS](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/tk2tS/)

Comment: I just noticed I didn't account for `border` in the `#wrap` width but that doesn't seem to matter too much.

Comment: Can't resist upvoting (this is how it *should* be), but it's unfortunately just not a practical solution :( As you said, it doesn't work in [the most popular browser](http://gs.statcounter.com/).

Comment: I could not believe my eyes that this works in ie6 (emulator)

Comment: @Rito: The elements are not in the desired order in any version of IE.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a pure CSS solution.

You said:

> Note: I already solved it by splitting
>   the list in two parts by PHP, but I
>   want to know, if there is a HTML/CSS
>   solution here.

So, you have the *power of PHP*. In that case, I would keep the code you already have, but output the elements in a different order:

See: http://jsfiddle.net/xyLkz/

```
<div class="list_item">A</div>
<div class="list_item">E</div>
<div class="list_item">B</div>
<div class="list_item">F</div>
<div class="list_item">C</div>
<div class="list_item">G</div>
<div class="list_item">D</div>
<div class="list_item">H</div>
```

How easy that will be depends on how your PHP is structured.

If you have everything in an array, then in this case, you would just have two loops (one outputting odd array elements, the other even ones). If you need support for `n` columns, that wouldn't be a problem either.

What *would* be a problem is if you're building the output "on-the-fly", inside the loop. In that case, you'd probably have to resort to buffering the output of each iteration of the loop into an array, and then doing the same double-loop process afterwards.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: But he *can* change it. If his current solution uses PHP to make two lists, then he can just as easily use it to output the elements in two loops. My solution is the only one that actually *works*.

Comment: @thirtydot: (a) Your solution is _not_ the only one that "works"; (b) Whether he can or not is besides the point... the question says that he doesn't want to. Valid answers do not involve changing the markup.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: The other answers only work in modern browsers, and not IE, which happens to be the [most popular browser worldwide](http://gs.statcounter.com/). Using a JavaScript library to replace the functionality is a bad idea - why do it client-side when you can do it server-side. The idea of answering a question is not to strictly adhere to the words in the question, but to find the **best solution** to the problem. I listed the possible downsides to my technique in my answer, so I think your downvote is unwarranted and highly annoying.

Comment: John's answer "works" just fine cross-browser, whether you think it's a "bad idea" or not ("why do it client-side when you can do it server-side" is hardly a rationale as to why it "doesn't work"). Although I agree that the best SO answers find the best solution to the problem, the problem here states _explicitly_ and _in no uncertain terms_ that the OP wants a solution without changing markup, and you have flagrantly ignored that. That's more annoying than losing a little bit of rep on 12.9k (blimey, how petty!).

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: How about this then, if you want to be so pedantic about what was *explictly stated* in the question. `"but I want to know, if there is a HTML/CSS solution"` - a **HTML/CSS** solution - John's answer requires **JavaScript** to work cross-browser (like in Internet Explorer, **the most popular browser in the world**). Therefore, only my answer works. The OP is already using PHP to change his HTML, so he might as well change it in a different way. The change I'm suggesting is **logically sensible**, despite the OP having stated that he doesn't wish to change the markup.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Also, I don't care about the reputation. I care that you're downvoting the most practical answer in the thread.. :/

Comment: @thirtydot: He didn't say it had to be cross-browser. Who cares about IE?! :P Your definition of "the most practical" is flawed until you can prove that most of _the OP's users_ use IE, and/or that he cares.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Are you serious?!? The logical assumption is that support for all **major market share** browsers is required, unless the OP has said (and here's your favourite word again) **explicitly** something like "I'm developing for WebKit browsers only", or "I don't care about users of Internet Explorer". He hasn't said *anything of the sort*. You think an answer that (in the words of @Marcel) contains "not really production-ready code" is better than one that Just Works? Why do they deserve upvotes, but mine deserves downvotes? They each have downsides.

Comment: @thirtydot: You're just being childish now. I don't understand why you're failing to comprehend that you wrote an answer that contravenes what the OP asked for. I'm done with this conversation. If you have a problem with the answer that myself and others have upvoted to a total of 5 (see, it's not just me) then I suggest you make explicit complaints on the relevant answer's comment thread.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: So you've run out of facts, so you're giving up the discussion; hey, whatever works for you. **Even I** voted up that answer, because (I agree with it and) **it is good**, but in a different way to my answer. I already did `"make explicit complaints on the relevant answer's comment thread"` - I said `"Can't resist upvoting (this is how it should be), but it's unfortunately just not a practical solution :( As you said, it doesn't work in the most popular browser."` - or did you also miss that comment? It wouldn't be the first thing you've missed in this question.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: My real irritation is that you're supposed to downvote answers that are [NOT USEFUL](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down). From that page: `"Whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect, vote it down!"` - would you say that my viable answer fits that profile? I didn't think so. Hence why I'm not dropping this argument.

Comment: @thirtydot: Then you can continue it on your own.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Then I might have to spend some time reading your answers, and downvoting those that do not *explicitly* (in my opinion) adhere to the words in the question. That's what you've done in this question, and frankly: it's annoying. Now, I'm not actually likely to do that, but I sure do feel like doing it. I actually cannot believe how *pedantic* you are - it's insane.

Answer (score 1):

@ silver

i try for side without using extra markup  may it's useful to you

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/GGwPq/1/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use float for the items, but maybe for a box where the items are located in, try this:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
    <div class="list_item">A</div>
    <div class="list_item">B</div>
    <div class="list_item">C</div>
    <div class="list_item">D</div>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
    <div class="list_item">E</div>
    <div class="list_item">F</div>
    <div class="list_item">G</div>
    <div class="list_item">H</div>
</div>

.list_item {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;

    width: 200px;
    /*float: left;*/
}
```

Edit: now with 2 columns :)

Comment: This will output one column, but I would like see two columns

Comment: I edited my post, didn't read your text correctly, sry :S
But now it should be the right solution

Comment: There is no other way? I mentioned in the question, that I cannot change the markup.

Comment: If you have 2 arrays in PHP, one with the values A, C, E, G and the other with B, E, F, H then you could add the items in a loop like this:
foreach ($i = 0; $i < count($arr_div_left); $i++) { // use the array with the highest count
echo '<div class="item">'.$arr_div_left[$i].'</div>';
echo '<div class="item">'.$arr_div_right[$i].'</div>';}

Comment: But there is no HTML/CSS way for that. The PHP-way isn't that bad I think, but he have to create the 2 arrays first. Another way would be, to loop trough all the values and create 2 strings with the content for the 2 boxes. if ($i % 2 == 0) $add_to_box1 else $add_to_box2

Comment: +1 to offset Mr Downvote-Answers-I-Don't-Like, and because I just noticed you had the "2 loops in PHP idea" before I did, which I think is the way to go.

Comment: Who is "Mr Downvote-Answers-I-Don't-Like"? It can't be me, I didn't vote for anything :P

Comment: @Kevin Glier: It's @Tomalak Geret'kal. I don't particularly like that he comes into a question, upvotes the two answers that aren't practical to actually use (CSS3 column-based, and the JavaScript alternative is even worse.. why do it client-side when you can do it server-side), and downvotes the two answers that suggest (even if your suggestion of this is only in a comment) using PHP to reorder the elements (a good solution, I think).