# How to modify the orientation of a <ul> spanning multiple columns?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am producing a `<ul>` of alphabetically sorted items, which spans over multiple lines. An example of this can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/H4FPw/1/

currently the list is laid out horizontally, as follows:

```
a  b  c

d  e  f

g  h  i

j  k  l
```

But clients being clients, I have now been asked to change this so that the list is vertically oriented, as follows:

```
a  e  i

b  f  j

c  g  k

d  h  l
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to do this in the nice and tidy way that I've originally done it.

Can somebody please fill me in if this is possible to do with single `<ul>` and CSS? Or do I have to make multiple lists?

Comment: Don't think it would be possible with just 1 ul. Do you use some backend code (like PHP for example?)

Comment: Its easily possible to do if you use some server scripting language.

Comment: @PeeHaa, yeah, all the back end is C#.. I guess I'll have to get my *code freak* on (as a nod & a wink at @Coding-Freak)

Comment: ;) you mean something like this? :D

Comment: What witchcraft is this @Coding-Freak?!

Comment: dude, I know! ;-)
It can be difficult to convey humour in text, but I did mean it. Honest!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it by only changing CSS.

Well, you can if you don't care about IE: http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20column

You have to compromise somewhere:

- Split the `<ul>` into three `<ul>`s manually.
- As hinted at by @PeeHaa, use server-side code to change the *order* that the `<li>`s are output (but still keep them inside one `<ul>`).
- Use JavaScript to reorder the `<li>`s. I did this using [jQuery here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114173/how-to-make-cakephps-habtm-checkboxes-alphabetical-top-to-bottom-in-columns/6117227#6117227), but it would probably make more sense to use a plugin like this: http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use multiple lists, just some matrices math.

I took a stab at it here so as long as initially it's alphabetically ordered horizontally and row and column is known, you can transform it with jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/H4FPw/12/

Edit: Oh yeah, I added an `id="place"` attribute to the `<ul>`.

Comment: I have to say this is a beautiful algorithm. There's only one problem with it though, which is that the rowcount is hard-coded at 4. In reality, I can have any number of list items, which means any number of rows. I've tried varying the rowcount but if I do, it either fails or outputs inconsistent results. Is there anything that can be done to rectify this? Thanks :-)

Comment: this is an excellent answer. Unfortunately, I've had to deselect it as correct in favour of @thirtydot's answer. The reason is because it actually fits my needs more specifically, which is something that I accidentally overlooked yesterday. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [CSS3 columns](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html) or JavaScript. IDK if it's possible by CSS2.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it in `PHP` you can use a simple counter and `%`. I've managed to accomplish this in `WordPress` getting a list of custom taxonomies like so:

```
<div class="row gutters">

    <?php $taxos = get_categories ( array( 'taxonomy' => 'make' ) ); ?>

    <?php $count = 0; ?>

    <div class="col col_2">

        <ul>

            <?php foreach( $taxos as $tax ) : ?>

                <li><a href="/make/<?php echo $tax->slug; ?>"><?php echo $tax->name; ?></a></li>

                <?php $count++; ?>

                <?php if( $count % 5 == 0 ) echo '</div></ul><div class="col col_2"><ul>'; ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

You can also loop through an array and acheive the same thing. Output looks something like:

```
a    f
b    g
c    h
d    i
e    j
```