# Floating divs like desktop icons

Tags: html, css

I have 15 Divs with 200px x 200px sized. I also having a container div which height set to 100%.

I need to display the Divs vertically one by one and when its reached the end of the container  height, The following divs should display in the second column.

I exactly need my divs to display like floating icons in desktop in PC.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: Did u check z-index property of css!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by setting css column-count property of ul to number of columns

This link explain more about this solution

[How to make floating DIV list appear in columns, not rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484215/how-to-make-floating-div-list-appear-in-columns-not-rows)